# Paginar en java ee jsf desde datos o archivos ingresados por el usuario

Tags: jsf, primefaces, archivo, java-ee

La consulta especifica es: nosotros estamos usando JSF con Framework Primefaces
Resulta que necesitamos mostrar en pantalla Datos Paginados
Tenemos una lista de objetos y cada objeto tiene un TITULO y CONTENIDO, eso lo debemos
mostrar en algún componente UN objeto por PAGINA.
Nosotros estuvimos viendo DataList con Paginación (PrimeFaces) eso es lo que necesitamos…El
inconveniente es que me muestra todo los objetos en la MISMA PAGINA

```
        <p:dataList id="paginacionTeorico" value="#{teoricoControlador.listaTeoricosIdTema}" var="teorico" widgetVar="teo" rows="1"  paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="2,4,6" type="none" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" >


            <p:column>
                <p:panel header="#{teorico.titulo}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{teorico.contenido}"/>

                </p:panel>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataList>

    </h:form>

</div>
```

ManagedBean

```
public List<Teorico> getListaTeoricosIdTema() throws PersistenciaExcepcion {

    Map<String, String> parametro = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(parametro.get("idTema"));

    return listaTeoricosIdTema = fachada.listarTeoricosPorId(id);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ Seel G!, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tenga buenas respuestas, aporta más detalles como tu cíodigo y trata de ser más especific@ en lo que preguntas. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que yo veo de diferencias entre tu código y el de [primefaces datalist](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml), te hace falta `styleClass="paginated"` como esta en el tercer ejemplo:

`<p:dataList value="#{dataListView.cars3}" var="car" type="unordered" itemType="none" paginator="true" rows="10" styleClass="paginated">`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, pudimos solucionarlo !

Comment: Recuerda votar por la pregunta que mas te ayudo.